# SDR lose samples at high bandwidth (sample rate)

Tags: software-defined-radio

When receiving bandwidth (sample rate) is small (<~28 MHz), the signals are received without any distortion. When I choose high bandwidth (for example 40 MHz), sometimes the signals become interrupted for a small amount of time and/or some noise is added. At the same time CPU utilization is about 40-60%. I use different USB ports (USB 3, USB 3.1), the result is the same.

How can I solve this problem?

Hardware:

- BladeRF xA4
- i7 8750H
- 16 GB RAM
- USB 3, USB 3.1

Software:

- SDRSharp
- SDR++
- Windows 10

Comment: I would try moving to Linux and gnuradio. in my experience, Windows is just not reliable for this kind of work.

Comment: this might be a bit of a performance tuning issue, and solvable, or it might just be that the things you want to do to the signal at higher rates simply can't be done at a throughput higher than your sampling rate, and there's no solution employing your current hardware. So, the question really becomes, what is it that you want to *do* with the signals? You list two different softwares that I'm at best superficially familiar with, but it's not really clear what of the signal processing features of these you actually need to happen at high rates

Comment: For example, listening to several frequencies simultaneously using AUX VFO plugin (airband and 2m ham band).

Comment: yeah, so you don't need SDRSharp or SDR++ working on the full > 28 MHz for that. So, you'd usually start by channelizing your full received baseband into the bands you need, discarding unnecessary bandwidth. Then you'd implement active channel selection and demodulation on the different bands separately, making sure to distribute the workload across CPU cores. MBaz is right, GNU Radio is an easy way to address the issues of channelization and distribution. I've got little Windows performance experience, and none involving BladeRF hardware, so I can't comment on whether Linux would be better

Comment: I noticed that the receiving is much more better if I disable spectrum and waterfall views in SDRSharp. 
How can I use channelizing technique? To receive a few frequencies from a large bandwidth I must specify high sample rate and then apply several resamplers to appropriate parts in which I interested in but that what is done in SDRSharp. Am I wrong somewhere?